# update modal bootstrap and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

-when i update with ajax , he changed but he only took to 'id' not the new variable

But I want to insert my E-Mail to database through Ajax. I don't want my page to get redirected, because every time the page got refreshed, null value got inserted to the database..

1)and ajax

```
function editdata(str){
   var id= str;
   var name  = $('#nameofequipe-'+str).val();
      $.ajax({
       type:"post",
       url: "<?php echo API;?>equipe/update.php",
       data:"nameofequipe="+name+"&id="+id,
       success:function(data){
        alert('success update data ');}
```

2)and modal bootstrap

```
  <div 
    class="modal fade" 
    id="edit-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" 
    role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="updatelLabel-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>    
<input 
    type="hidden"  
    id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"  
    value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"  >
<input 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    id="nameofequipe-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" 
    value="<?php echo $row['equipe']; ?>">
```

if somoene know how i can do This can He help me

Comment: Hi. It would be good to see the PHP code that is running on the server

Comment: yes i see but he goes to update.php but he took only the id of this , and sometimes he gets Null

Comment: Right, but you may be doing something wrong in the PHP code

Comment: Hi @MarketLink to offer a better help would be nice to show us where you call the function js "editdata(str)" ( what data is "str")  and see the PHP code if possible.

Comment: it is variable from the button           <button type="submit" onclick='editdata(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)' class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

Answer (score 0):

//use this in script section

```
function editdata(str){
        var id= str;
        var name  = $('#nameofequipe-'+str).val();
        $.ajax({
         dataType: "json",
        type:"post",
        url: "<?php echo API;?>equipe/update.php",
        data:"{nameofequipe:"+name+",id:"+id+"}",
        success:function(data){
        alert('success update data ');

    }
```

//whereas this one in your PHP file where you use this data **nameOfEquipe and Id** to update you **database**.

```
 if(isset($_POST['nameofequipe'], $_POST['id']) {
        $nameOfEquip=$_POST['nameofequipe'];
        $id=$_POST['id'];

      }
```

Comment: dosnt function he still took the id

Answer (score 0):

This Is all code

```
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">

    </button>
  </div>
  <form>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >


<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameofequipe-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['equipe']; ?>">
```

```
  </div>
          <button type="submit" onclick='editdata(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)' class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

  </div>
  </form>
```

ajax and js

```
          function editdata(str) 

  {
          var id= str;
         var name= $('#nameofequipe-'+str).val();
          $.ajax ({
          type:"post",
            url: "<?php echo API;?>equipe/update.php",
          data:"nameofequipe="+name+"&id="+id,
        success: function(data){
        alert("Data Save: " + data);

  }

    }); }
```

update. PHP

```
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $name=$_POST['nameofequipe'];


    $result  = $o->SelectQuery("UPDATE rh_equipes SET equipe='$name'  WHERE id='$id'");
    if($result){
       echo 'data update';
 }
```